# Update highcharts options via setoptions after the charts have been rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

We are making use of Highcharts for our data visualization application which has about 20 or charts. The charts are showing cost information and we are adding the ability for users to change currency. Now because we can change currency we would like to change our prefix to on yaxis. More specifically we change our label formatter option using

```
HighCharts.setOptions({
yAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return `${currency} ${formatCostNumberStr(this.value)}`;
        }
      }
    }
})
```

`currency` is passed into the function which gets called everytime currency changes.

The issue is that these new options will not take place until the charts rerender - which is fine as long as the data is different but if the data remains the same (i.e. values remain same) the charts yaxis will not change. Is there a way to rerender all the charts at the same time?

Comment: Hi @Tushar Chutani, Instead of using `Highcharts.setOptions`, you need to update each chart. Could you provide me with a live example that presents how some of your charts are implemented in React? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: The charts are very generic so the example that you gave would be a good one. The issue is that we have about 14 to 15 graphs. Updating each chart is definitely doable but since we are talking about currency everytime a chart is added we would have to change the options there.

Comment: I have created a new very simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fo-sxwvv?file=/demo.jsx of how you can exactly implement the required functionality.